# How to compile Objective-C files on Windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, visual-studio-code

I have multiple Objective-C source files. But I don't know where I can compile them. I'm not familiar with Objective-C either. So is there any platform to compile all the source files of Objective-C?
(Help me with VSCode too, if I can achieve it with VSCode simply)

Comment: gcc supports obj-c & obj-c++;

Comment: On macOS the easiest way is Xcode. Or you could use clang or gcc directly. But, to be honest, have you tried googling your question before posting here? Providing info about the platform that you're using could be also a good start.

Comment: How can i install gcc Or clang.It shows a whole big process invloving configuration and all. And i have windows

Comment: Building ObjC code on Windows is not always trivial. It highly depends on what the ObjC relies on. For example, it may be GNUstep code, in which case you'll need the GNUstep libraries. Or it may require CoreFoundation, in which case you'll need those. If it requires Darwin's Foundation (i.e. macOS), it may not be portable to Windows at all. We'd need more information about the specifics of this code. Do you believe it is supposed to run on Windows? For info on setting up a compiler, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63914108/using-clang-in-windows-10-for-c-c

Comment: I think you can use cygwin or it's analogs.